# Exponential distribution in queue model M/M/1

Tags: exponential-distribution, queueing-theory

Let's say I have $60$ time intervals and I want to generate appearance of people where time between their appearances is selected using exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. How do I do it?

Comment: Is your question about how to sample from the exponential distribution?

Comment: No. I will try to explain on an example. Let's assume $T_0=0,T_1=1$. Assume $N$ people arrive at time $0<t_0,t_1,…,t_N<1$. $t_i > t_j$ for $i>j$. Values $|t_i-t_{i+1}|$ are drawn from exponential distribution with mean of $\lambda$ people in interval. The question is how to calculate number $N$ of people that arrived in this interval.

Answer (score 0):

If the intervals between successive arrivals are independent and follow an $\text{Exponential}(\lambda)$ distribution, we call this a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$.

The number of arrivals in any time interval of length $t$ has the $\text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ distribution.